# How to setup apple's in-app purchase with a react-native webview?

Tags: react-native, webview, in-app-purchase, applepay

I've created a react-native app for android and ios with a webview that embeds my website.

As Apple and Google forces people to use their own in-app purchase system I've been looking for how to do that using a webview.

I've found https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments but that only works for react-native directly and not with a webview.

Anyone has ever done that/knows if it's possible?